# Magento 2: Add to Cart JS Override works on product page but not on category page

Tags: magento2, javascript, catalog, addtocart, magento-2.1.4

I override **magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\web\js\catalog-add-to-cart.js**

as I need to change the text from "Add to Cart" to "Buy Now"

**magento\app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
  "map": {
    "*": {
      "Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart": "Custom_Module/js/catalog-add-to-cart"
    }
  }
};
```

It works fine on Product Page, but on Category page it still goes to Main File not override file.

Why?

Comment: Did you change in templates also?

Comment: Yes I have applied changes in Templates as well @KhoaTruongDinh

Comment: @AnkitShah Same issue i have found. Is there any solution you have found?

Comment: @AnkitShah Please check my answer. I had the same issue and I've resolved that.

Answer (score 6):

You can override add to cart js via mixin.

1 : In your `magento\app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js`

Add following code.

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart': {
                'Custom_Module/js/catalog-add-to-cart-mixin': true
            },
        }
    }
};
```

2 : Put your add to cart file with named `catalog-add-to-cart-mixin.js` under `app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\web\js\`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate',
    'jquery/ui',
], function ($, $t,alert) {
    'use strict';

    return function (widget) {
      console.log('catalog-add-to-cart-mixin');

    $.widget('mage.catalogAddToCart', widget, {

    });

    return $.mage.catalogAddToCart;
  }
});
```

Comment: actually good answer! I will add one more answer for those who unable to get hint from above answer to override function.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I resolved the issue by this code.

1 => In your app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js

Add following code.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
         'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart':'Custom_Module/js/catalog-add-to-cart',
         catalogAddToCart:'Custom_Module/js/catalog-add-to-cart'
        }
    }
};
```

2 => Put your add to cart file in app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\web\js path with name catalog-add-to-cart.js

Now you can copy paste the parent file code in the overridden file and make your changes.

Above code will override the file and also replace the parent file

Answer (score 2):

After Following Zed:
Further if you want to modify any function you need to add it in side $.wiget block:
Like in my case I want to preserve my buttons text to "Pre Order" what I do is:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate',
    'jquery/ui'
], function($, $t) {
    "use strict";

    return function (widget) {

        $.widget('mage.catalogAddToCart', widget, {

            disableAddToCartButton: function(form) {
                this.options.addToCartButtonTextDefault = $(form).find(this.options.addToCartButtonSelector).find('span').text();
                this._super(form); // parent call
            }
        });

        return $.mage.catalogAddToCart;
    }
});
```

You can override function the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: 
Lets try rename `catalog-add-to-cart` from  `Custom_Module/js/catalog-add-to-cart` to `Custom_Module/js/catalog-add-to-cartt` ( double T )

> File magento\app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {


"map": {
"*": {
  "Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart": "Custom_Module/js/catalog-add-to-cartt"
     }
  }
};
```

Step 2:

```
/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

and

```
/bin/magento c:f`
```

Step 3:

change `catalog-add-to-cartt` in `requirejs-config.js` file  to `catalog-add-to-cart`.

And change name `catalog-add-to-cartt.js` to `catalog-add-to-cart.js`

```
/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

and

```
/bin/magento c:f
```

It's working for me