# How to get prices on category and product page via ajax

Tags: magento2, javascript, price, ajax

I am using the mageworx customer special price module.
But it messes up my cache by adding a unique user id to the cache generation. How can I hide prices and add them on load using ajax?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Ui Components` in this case, to get or modify the price in the category or product pages.

no need to use AJAX calls use `Ui Components` instead

[Its well described here in this guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/howto/price_rendering.html)

1. locate the javascript ui components used in the product and category pages
2. Override them in your requirejs
3. use a mix-in and get or modify the prices

added a few links below for your reference

[Format price with javascript in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108388/format-price-with-javascript-in-magento-2)

[Magento2 - How to use Magento_Catalog/js/price-box to format price in template?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151244/magento2-how-to-use-magento-catalog-js-price-box-to-format-price-in-template)

[Magento 2: How to include JS on the product page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114327/magento-2-how-to-include-js-on-the-product-page)

[Magento2: How can I override core js module price-box.js](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112102/magento2-how-can-i-override-core-js-module-price-box-js)

[Magento 2: Add to Cart JS Override works on product page but not on category page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163531/magento-2-add-to-cart-js-override-works-on-product-page-but-not-on-category-pag)